# How to add rows together into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine monthly rows into half year rows and group on Name and ProfitabilityProductId and put it to new table

[Data as is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVFlJ.png)

[Data to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tssh4.png)

I just posted the example as i would like it in Excel as I of cause can't do it in SQL.

```
SELECT TOP 20 [FactDt]
,[Name]
,[ProfitabilityProductId]
,[RateX]
,[RateY]

FROM [D7D7].[fact].[FacilityIncome_V]
```

Comment: I think the word "multiply" is not well chosen here, what you want seems to be additions, isn't it? Maybe you should clarify on which calculus is made to get to the new data. You should also precise what SQL DBRMS you wan to use for this

Comment: Yes you are right. It is not to multiply the row.
The calculation is simply to add the values together.

As i am new to SQL I don't know what SQL DBRMS is. I can tell that i am using Microsoft SQL 2016 to do this.

Comment: Yes, but don't expect people to analyse all the data to guess how you combined the rows, wether you just add the values, multiply them or anything, it should be in the question

Comment: From your data screenshots and description. I'm still unclear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Is it being grouped by Name, ProfitabilityProductId, and Quarter, then taking the sum of RateX to get your first column, sum of RateY for the second column? Are you trying to group by quarter, as the first column of your Data to be implies, or half year, as your description says? Are your screenshots complete datasets for your example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR,[FactDt]), 'Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, [FactDt]))
    ,[Name]
    ,[ProfitabilityProductId]
    ,SUM([RateX])
    ,SUM([RateY])
FROM [D7D7].[fact].[FacilityIncome_V]
GROUP BY 
    [ProfitabilityProductId], DATEPART(YEAR,[FactDt]),  DATEPART(QUARTER,[FactDt]), [Name]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work! The only problem is that i have many million rows so it runs forever. that is of cause not something i can do anything about, I guess..

Comment: Any idea how to get the data in half year data instead of quaterly if i wish to do this?

Comment: this should work `((DATEPART(quarter,[Date])-1)/2)+1`

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your question, that you cannot export the results to Excel but that is not entirely true. I have in the past bypassed SQL Server's limitations using SQL CLR. What this means is you can write the required action to be performed in .Net and call that code using the generated Stored Procedure (once added under assemblies in SQL Server), which calls that code under the hood.

To get started with SQL CLR go here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-2017

To get started with the TSQL to Excel example go here:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/xlsexport-a-clr-procedure-to-export-proc-results-to-excel